# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parent'

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am building an application in Google App Engine with Cloud Datastore backend.

My Model Base class

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

```
class CFCModel(ndb.Model):
    """
    Base model from which we can inherit other models. Test
    """
    created_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    modified_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

The class the model inherits is

```
class PraiseReport(CFCModel):
    def __init__(self):
        self.username = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
        self.report = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
        super(PraiseReport, self).__init__()
```

I am now trying to create an object

```
key = PraiseReportRepository.get_praise_report_key()
praise_report_model = PraiseReport(parent=key)
praise_report_model.username = praise_report.username
praise_report_model.report = praise_report.report
praise_report_model.put()
```

And I get the following error

```
ERROR    2016-05-25 09:34:59,882 app.py:1423] Exception on /forms/add_praise_report [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/CM-12/server/lib/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/CM-12/server/lib/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/CM-12/server/lib/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/CM-12/server/lib/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/CM-12/server/lib/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/CM-12/cfc/decorators/authentication.py", line 62, in authenticate_and_call_member
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/CM-12/Routes/PraiseReportRoutes.py", line 34, in add_report
    repo.add(report)
  File "/Users/vinay/App-Engine/CM-12/cfc/data/PraiseReportRepository.py", line 12, in add
    praise_report_model = PraiseReport(parent=key)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parent'
```

Comment: As you can see there is no `parent` variable in those classes. So this `parent=key` will give you an error

Comment: So how do I set that value given the base class has such a property ?

Comment: Looks like you are confusing the concept of a GAE `parent` with a Python `superclass`.  I suggest reading about each so you can learn what the differences are.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few errors here. Your main one is that you have overridden the `__init__` method so that it does not accept any parameters, but then you are trying to call it *with* parameters. Obviously, your subclass method should accept the same parameters as the base class, and pass those parameters into the `super` call - usually that is done with `*args, **kwargs`.

However it does not look like you should be overriding `__init__` at all here. The only code you have in that overridden method most definitely does not belong there. Fields must always be defined at class level; they will simply not work if you define them inside a method. Move those fields out, and remove that method altogether.

```
class PraiseReport(CFCModel):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    report = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```